# Notable XSS attacks in 2011

Tags: xss, historical

I am wondering what notable events in XSS attacks we saw in 2011. What big events hit the infosec community in regards of XSS?

I am thinking of specific events like for example the [Samy worm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28computer_worm%29) in 2007 or the HBGary SQL Injection attack in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were quite a few, but the ones that got a lot of news time over here:

- [3 on Facebook](http://theharmonyguy.com/2011/04/21/recent-facebook-xss-attacks-show-increasing-sophistication/)
- [CIA](http://thehackernews.com/2011/06/xss-attack-on-cia-central-itelligence.html)
- [UK Police](http://www.news-h.com/2011/09/xss-attack-on-policeuk-website-by.html)
- [FBI](http://www.cyberwarnews.info/2011/08/08/fbi-xss-attack-by-tehwongz/)